# powershell remote import module error

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a problem with this code

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $CSC_SERVER -ScriptBlock { 
    Import-Module ("C:\Build_v.6.1.0.9\Tools\CommonComponents.BuildCommands.dll")
}
```

Error:

Could not load file or assembly "file: /// C: \ Build V.6.1.0.9 \ Tools \ CommonComponents.BuildCommands.dll" or one of their dependent components. The assembly created in a later version of the runtime than the current, and can not be loaded.

When I go to the server via RDP and try to load this module everything is OK.

how to fix this problem?

**UPD**

```
> Invoke-Command -ComputerName $CSC_SERVER -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5420
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
```

And same via local session on remove server

```
> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.17929
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Now I see that difference in CLRVersion. Powershell remoting uses CLR version 2.0. What is the reason for this behavior? And how to change it to version 4.0?

Comment: Could you post results of `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $CSC_SERVER -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable}` and `$PSVersionTable` from `powershell.exe` in RDP session?